# stuck at a while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop, freeze

soooo this code is supposed to generate as many fake identities as you ask for, but it never does!!

for example when I request 10 identities, I only get two, or just one sometimes, and then it just stops, i mean the code would be still running but it won't generate any more identities, it just freezes.

note:  i tried to run the code on more than one computer and the same thing happens every single time.

The code:

```
import random
from lists import name_m, name_f, month, cars_m, to_cars, fo_cars, ho_cars

choice = input('info or {pro}gram: ')
if choice == 'pro':
    gl = 0
    fr_name = ''
    l_name = ''
    gl1 = int(input('number of people:'))
    names_l = input('(M)ale , (F)emale :')
    while gl < gl1:
        if names_l.upper() == 'M':
            fr_name = random.choice(name_m)
            l_name = random.choice(name_m)
            while l_name == fr_name:
                fr_name = random.choice(name_m)
        elif names_l.upper() == 'F':
            fr_name = random.choice(name_f)
            l_name = random.choice(name_m)
            while l_name == fr_name:
                fr_name = random.choice(name_f)
        ph_num = random.sample('0123456789', 8)
        bi_y = random.randint(1960, 2017)
        bi_m = random.choice(month)
        bi_d = random.randint(1, 28)
        ex = random.randint(0, 40)
        age = 2020 - bi_y
        while age - 25 < ex:
            ex = random.randint(0, 40)
        yr = 'years'
        if ex == 1:
            yr = 'year'
        car_co = random.choice(cars_m)
        car_mo = ''
        if car_co == 'Ford':
            car_mo = random.choice(fo_cars)
        elif car_co == 'Toyota':
            car_mo = random.choice(to_cars)
        elif car_co == 'Honda':
            car_mo = random.choice(ho_cars)

        ph_nu = f'{ph_num[0]}{ph_num[1]}{ph_num[2]}{ph_num[3]}{ph_num[4]}{ph_num[5]}{ph_num[6]}{ph_num[7]}'
        email = random.choice(['gmail', 'hotmail', 'outlook'])
        cho = random.sample('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz', 5)
        cho_v = random.sample('aieuo', 5)
        cho_n = random.sample('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz1234567890', 4)
        ch = f'''{cho_n[0]}{cho_n[2]}{cho[0]}{cho_v[0]}{cho[1]}{cho_v[1]}{cho[2]}{cho_v[2]}{cho[3]}{cho_v[3]}{cho[4]}{cho_v[4]}{cho_n[2]}{cho_n[3]}'''
        nu = random.randint(5, 12)
        car = f'{car_co} {car_mo}'

        print(f'''
                    Name: {fr_name} {l_name}
                    Birthdate: {bi_y} {bi_m} {bi_d}
                    Phone number: 05{ph_nu}
                    Email: {ch[0:nu]}@{email}.com
                    Experience: {ex} {yr}
                    Car: {car}''')
        gl += 1
elif choice == 'info':
    print(f'Number of male names: {len(name_m)}')
    print(f'number of female names: {len(name_f)}')
    print(f'Total: {len(name_f + name_m)}')
```

Comment: This is quite a lot of code, that uses a lot of stuff you don't mention in your post (like everything from `lists`), which makes it harder for us to help debug. Can you condense it down to something shorter that produces the same issue that could help us debug? Have you stepped through this with a debugger to see what's wrong, or even just put in a bunch of `print` statements to see where the code is stopping?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

When `bi_y >= 1995` then you end up with `age - 25 < 0` so your while loop will never exit since `ex` cannot be `< 0`.

Change `bi_y = random.randint(1960, 2017)` to `bi_y = random.randint(1960, 1995)`

Comment: omggg thankssssss